# Compute range over list of `xts` objects

Tags: r, date, xts

In `R`, I've got a list of `xts` objects and I want to compute the range of the time index over all the items in the list.  I can't find a smooth way to do it though, it keeps losing the classes of the objects & becoming raw numeric vectors.

For example (my list is called `states`, it's indexed by a GMT `POSIXct`):

```
> c(min(sapply(states, start)), max(sapply(states, end)))
[1] 1252714110 1315785360

> range(sapply(states, function(x) range(index(x))))
[1] 1252714110 1315785360
```

It's a hassle to convert those back to `POSIXct`, I'm doing it like so:

```
minmax <- range(sapply(states, function(x) range(index(x))))
epoch <-   as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
rg <- as.POSIXct(minmax, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
```

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply` to find the index range of each list element.  Then use `do.call` to find the range of the list:

```
do.call(range, lapply(states, function(x) range(index(x))))
```

or, if you prefer a functional paradigm:

```
Reduce(range, Map(function(x) range(index(x)), states))
```

`sapply` doesn't work because the simplification process converts the output to an atomic vector or matrix with a single type of either: NULL < raw < logical < integer < real < complex < character < list < expression, in that order of precedence.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I suspected the problem was the simplification, but couldn't think of a way past it.